# Using the number 8 6 4 2 = either 19 or 17

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

The numbers can only be used once.
You can use any operator from BEDMAS.

Comment: If we interpret the "either...or" mathematically, as xor, we get the rather trivial solution: $2=19 \oplus 17$

Comment: Then it would be `8 / (6 - (4/2))`  :)

Answer (score 4):

One option:

> 6^2 / 4 + 8 = 17 (36 / 4 + 8 = 9 + 8 = 17)

Answer (score 4):

Here is 19

> $\frac{(8 \times 4) + 6}{2} = 19$